# AdMob Ads dont show Testenvironment .Net MAUI

Tags: android, admob, maui, .net-8.0

i got following problem
i wanted to add some Ads in my new Project in .Net MAUI which has the target Framework .Net8.0-android for now.

Things i already did i wanted to implement AdMob via the Plugin.MauiMTAdmob NuGget-Package.

1. I Installed the newest Version 1.3.1.
2. I implemented the ".UseMauiMTAdmob()

```
  builder
      .UseMauiApp<App>()
      .UseMauiMTAdmob()
```

3. i upgraded my Manifest.xml and added following

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT" android:value="true"/>
```

4. i upgraded my MainActivity

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MobileAds.Initialize(this);
    }
```

5.i implemented in XAML Code

```
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <controls:MTAdView x:Name="AdView" AdsId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Plugin.MauiMTAdmob.Controls;assembly=Plugin.MauiMTAdmob"`

And now if im starting it i get following Log

[device log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtlRL.png)

I created my AdMob Account yesterday, my Account got approved my App is outstanding because i didnt released it anywhere now.
But for test purposes i can use the Test Ad Id as i did i thought.
Otherwise i Added my Phone as Testphone to use it with my own Banner but this also doesnt work.

Ah and im Debugging with my Phone and not the Emulator.

Does anyone know what am i missing?

Greetings